# Using command line to compress a .bak file and moving the zip file

Tags: command-line, zip, compression, command-prompt, copy-paste

I am trying to use command line to zip a `.bak` file then cut the zip file to another location or copy/paste and delete the original once the copy is complete.

Right now my script is

```
copy "\\a\*.bak" "\\b"
```

I would like to compress the `.bak` file (in folder a) as it is a huge file, and then CUT the zip file into folder b.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a built-in functionality for this.

```
tar.exe -a -c -f file_Output.zip your_file.bak
```

file_Output.zip will be the file you will get as your zipped file, your_file.bak will be the file you are trying to compress.